# tmux "can't create socket: Operation not permitted"

Tags: osx, tmux

I recently restarted my computer (I'm on OSX and have tmux installed via homebrew) and upon doing so found that tmux stopped working completely.

```
$ tmux
can't create socket: Operation not permitted
```

I have no idea where this came from, how to troubleshoot it or even how to get more detailed information about the error. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I'm happy to modify this post with additional information but I don't even know where to look.

In case this helps

```
$ ls -la $(which tmux)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 stephen  admin  27 Oct  4 10:04 /usr/local/bin/tmux -> ../Cellar/tmux/2.3/bin/tmux


$ ls -l /private
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  100 root  wheel  3400 Oct  4 10:11 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel    68 Aug 22  2015 tftpboot
drwxrwxrwt@   3 root  wheel   102 Oct  4 09:08 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   25 root  wheel   850 Feb 29  2016 var

$ ls /private/tmp
noticeboard

$ ls -l /                                                      
total 45
drwxrwxr-x+ 132 root     admin  4488 Sep 30 16:49 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+  65 root     wheel  2210 Jul  9 18:13 Library
drwxr-xr-x@   2 root     wheel    68 Dec  7  2015 Network
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root     wheel   136 Feb 29  2016 System
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     admin   170 May 20 13:33 Users
drwxrwxrwt@   4 root     admin   136 Oct  4 10:18 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@  39 root     wheel  1326 Feb 29  2016 bin
drwxrwxr-t@   2 root     admin    68 Dec  7  2015 cores
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     wheel   102 May 24 16:08 data
dr-xr-xr-x    3 root     wheel  4549 Oct  4 10:12 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel    11 Dec  7  2015 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     wheel     1 Oct  4 10:12 home
-rw-r--r--@   1 root     wheel   313 Aug 22  2015 installer.failurerequests
drwx------    6 stephen  staff   204 Sep 27 17:44 macOS Install Data
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     wheel     1 Oct  4 10:12 net
drwxrwxr-x@   5 root     wheel   170 Apr 10 23:40 opt
drwxr-xr-x@   6 root     wheel   204 Oct  4 09:08 private
drwxr-xr-x@  59 root     wheel  2006 Feb 29  2016 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel    11 Dec  7  2015 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@  13 root     wheel   442 Apr 10 23:58 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel    11 Dec  7  2015 var -> private/var
```

Comment: Looks like it yes. I edited the post to include the outputs from those. The socket does not appear to be there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a permission problem on the temporary folder.
The folder permissions should be 1777 (on linux the command is):

```
sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp
```

A radical approach would be to start over and remove the temporary folders associated with tmux (on linux):

```
sudo rm -r /tmp/tmux-*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's what fixed it for me:

```
sudo chflags -R norestricted /private/tmp/
```

With System Integrity Protection disabled.

I got this fix from theDarkAngle on the [Apple discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7695049). He credits this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/55s9yg/getting_an_error_message_on_startup_coretelephony/)

Answer (score 0):

What got it working for me was just installing the newest version of OSX (OS Sierra in my case) and the problem went away.

I don't know what that tells us about the root cause or if it work for everyone but it worked for me. YMMV.